# Meteor Error: A method named insert is already defined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I had created a mongo collection named `votes`  Which was working properly even after updating the packages to latest meteor version. I don't remember changing any part of the working code however I am getting this errors. I had updated the project using `meteor update` command and tested it right after the update. It ran successfully that time but I have no clue why I'm getting this error. And, not sure which source file should I add to get help...

Can anyone shed some light?

```
W20141025-21:29:08.640(6)? (STDERR) 
W20141025-21:29:08.641(6)? (STDERR) /home/wasi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.k7p01x++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141025-21:29:08.641(6)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20141025-21:29:08.642(6)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20141025-21:29:08.693(6)? (STDERR) Error: A method named '/votes/insert' is already defined
W20141025-21:29:08.695(6)? (STDERR)     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1439
W20141025-21:29:08.696(6)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113)
W20141025-21:29:08.697(6)? (STDERR)     at _.extend.methods (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1437)
W20141025-21:29:08.697(6)? (STDERR)     at Mongo.Collection._defineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:884)
W20141025-21:29:08.698(6)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:208)
W20141025-21:29:08.699(6)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/collection.js:1:43
W20141025-21:29:08.700(6)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/collection.js:58:3
W20141025-21:29:08.701(6)? (STDERR)     at /home/wasi/AI/OVS/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141025-21:29:08.702(6)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141025-21:29:08.702(6)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/wasi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.k7p01x++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
[=================== ] 94% 4.8s
```

Comment: most probably you are redefining the `votes` collection.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Oh! got it. My backup folder of the project incidentally got pasted on the project root. Meteor merges all the sub directories hence, the `votes` collection got redefined. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Please note:** If you are currently using the [Angular-Meteor](http://www.angular-meteor.com) [tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/) to build the app *[Socially](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/)* and you are using an integrated development environment (IDE) like [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), which is able to automatically compile TypeScript to JavaScript, my answer will probably help you to solve this problem.

---

I received this error without redefining a collection. Later I found out that my IDE (WebStorm 2016.1) caused duplicates, because it automatically compiled TypeScript to JavaScript even though Meteor handles this job for us. Luckily I got rid of this error by just disabling the TypeScript Compiler in WebStorm and deleting the compiler output files.

So, if WebStorm asks you if you want to compile TypeScript to JavaScript, say **No**!

[image: WebStorm - Compile TypeScript to JavaScript]

If you have already messed up your setup, go to **WebStorm** → **Preferences** → **Languages & Frameworks** → **TypeScript** and uncheck the **"Enable TypeScript Compiler"** option:

[image: TypeScript Compiler in WebStorm Preferences]

After that, delete the TypeScript compiler output files:

[image: WebStorm TypeScript Compiler Output]

Now your application should work again. Happy coding!

Comment: I struggled with this problem for a whole day. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

your xyz.js file code is

```
  console.log("This is test panel ....");
  new Mongo.Collection('players');           <<-------remove This line 
    PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');
```

remove

```
new Mongo.Collection('players');
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this error because I had new'd the same mongo collection into two different variables.

e.g.

```
CrowdEstimates = new Mongo.Collection('crowdEstimates');
CrowdEstimateAggregations = new Mongo.Collection('crowdEstimates');
```

Cut and paste and distraction....

Answer (score 2):

I think You have the same names for your methods in `app/collections/collection.js`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message, it happened after I reorganized the folder structure of my application. I had a collection Javascript named `drivers.js` in a  folder named `both` and I had another Javascript file with the same name (and code) in `both\collections\drivers.js`.

So the error message is more-or-less correct. Just weird looking, at least on my system.